# Angular 2 - attach a component to a class dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a reusable component for my app, and do not have a constant template to it.

I mean, that I would like to let the developer to implement it's own template, and then use this component.

Googling and Stackoverflowing, I did not find a way to inject a template to the component on the fly.

Is there a way to create a class, and attach to it a component on the fly?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do in a more specific way? As i understand it you want a `directive` instead of a `component`.

Comment: Well, I want to have a component such that the developer would be able to inject a different femplate each time